# Why the XUnit attributs aren't recognised?

Tags: vb.net, xunit, xunit.net

I installed the libraries xUnit with NuGet, and added references but I have errors because of the attributes [Theory], [InlineData("11/12/2011","2011-11-12")] and [Fact].

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports FluentAssertions
Imports Xunit
Imports System
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports Xunit.Extensions

Public Class XUnitClassTest



[Theory]
[InlineData("11/12/2011","2011-11-12")]
Public Sub test(input As String, output As String)

    Dim pattern As String = "\d+|[A-Za-zÀàÂâÄäÇçÉéÈèÊêËëÎîÏïÔôÖöÙùÛûÜü']+"
    Dim matchList As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(input, pattern)
    Dim matchArray(matchList.Count - 1) As Match
    matchList.CopyTo(matchArray, 0)

    Dim manager As Processeur = New Processeur

    manager.GetData(matchArray.Select(Function(a) a.ToString())).Should().Be(output)

End Sub

[Fact]
Public Sub FactMethodName()

    Write(DateTime.Parse("1658").ToString())

End Sub


Public Shared Sub Write(format As String, ParamArray param As Object())

    Console.WriteLine(format, param)

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using C# attribute syntax in VB.NET.
VB.NET syntax would be

```
<Fact>
Public Sub FactMethodName()
    Write(DateTime.Parse("1658").ToString())
End Sub
```

and so on.